# How to pass json POST data to Web API method as an object?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET MVC4 Web API application defines post method to save customer.
Customer is passed in json format in POST request body.
Customer parameter in post method contains null values for properties.

How to fix this so that posted data will passed as customer object ?

If possible Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded should used since I dont know how to change it in javascript method which posts form.

Controller:

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController {

  public object Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new
            {
                customer = customer
            });
        }
    }
}

public class Customer
    {
        public string company_name { get; set; }
        public string contact_name { get; set; }
     }
```

Request:

```
POST http://localhost:52216/api/customers HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

{"contact_name":"sdfsd","company_name":"ssssd"}
```

Answer (score 561, accepted):

**EDIT** : 31/10/2017

The same code/approach will work for **Asp.Net Core 2.0** as well. The major difference is, In asp.net core, both web api controllers and Mvc controllers are merged together to single controller model. So your return type might be `IActionResult` or  one of it's implementation (Ex :`OkObjectResult`)

---

Use

```
contentType:"application/json"
```

You need to use `JSON.stringify` method to convert it to JSON string when you send it,

And the model binder will bind the json data to your class object.

The below code will work fine (tested)

```
$(function () {
    var customer = {contact_name :"Scott",company_name:"HP"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data :JSON.stringify(customer),
        url: "api/Customer",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
});
```

**Result**

[image]

`contentType` property tells the server that we are sending the data in JSON format. Since we sent a JSON data structure,model binding will happen properly.

If you inspect the ajax request's headers, you can see that  the `Content-Type` value is set as `application/json`.

If you do not specify contentType explicitly, It will use the default content type which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`

---

*Edit on Nov 2015 to address other possible issues raised in comments*

### Posting a complex object

Let's say you have a complex view model class as your web api action method parameter like this

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public string Name {set;get;}  
   public List<TagViewModel> Tags {set;get;}
}
public class TagViewModel
{
  public int Id {set;get;}
  public string Code {set;get;}
}
```

and your web api end point is like

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public CreateUserViewModel Save([FromBody] CreateUserViewModel m)
    {
        // I am just returning the posted model as it is. 
        // You may do other stuff and return different response.
        // Ex : missileService.LaunchMissile(m);
        return m;
    }
}
```

*At the time of this writing, ASP.NET MVC 6 is the latest stable version and in MVC6, Both Web api controllers and MVC controllers are inheriting from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` base class.*

To send data to the method from client side, the below code should work fine

```
//Build an object which matches the structure of our view model class
var model = {
    Name: "Shyju",
    Id: 123,
    Tags: [{ Id: 12, Code: "C" }, { Id: 33, Code: "Swift" }]
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: "../product/save",
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(res) {       
    console.log('res', res);
    // Do something with the result :)
});
```

### Model binding works for some properties, but not all ! Why ?

If you do not decorate the web api method parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public CreateUserViewModel Save(CreateUserViewModel m)
{
    return m;
}
```

And send the model(raw javascript object, not in JSON format) without specifying the contentType property value

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: model,
    url: "../product/save"
}).done(function (res) {
     console.log('res', res);
});
```

Model binding will work for the flat properties on the model, not the properties where the type is complex/another type. In our case, `Id` and `Name` properties will be properly bound to the parameter `m`, But the `Tags` property will be an empty list.

The same problem will occur if you are using the short version, `$.post` which will use the default Content-Type when sending the request.

```
$.post("../product/save", model, function (res) {
    //res contains the markup returned by the partial view
    console.log('res', res);
});
```

Comment: Not sure what I did, but I came back in this morning and back in the same boat.  Object is null in the controller.  here we go again lol

Comment: okay, 2 hours in and I cant figure this out. In my case just for testing I am am posting from fiddler. I have the content type set to Content-Type: application/json. I have a viewmodel that I am trying to bind the data too. I have gone as far as modifying the viewmodel so that it only contains a single element, 
{ \"AssetName\":\"testname\" }
and my controller looks like this 
[HttpPost] 
public HttpResponseMessage LogValidation([FromBody]myViewModel myviewmodel){ 
the post hits the controller but myviewmodel is always null.

Comment: @Grayson can you post a minimized sample solution so that i can take a look ?

Comment: make sure the content type is written "Content-Type: application/json" while you are using fiddler. Cheers!

Comment: You simply solved me a day of work!!!
This tiny function "JSON.stringify(data)" made it!

Comment: @Shyju what software you have used for display that information?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this (change the Content-Type header) and you're making a CORS request, jQuery will start adding preflight OPTIONS requests before your POST which the server will have to handle.

Comment: @Grayson - I know this is a year later but I am having the same really aggravating issue.  Using the proper application/json content-type; using json values that match a class.  But in the web api function the paramater is showing up as null.

Even more frustrating - I have another api function where a different class works just fine!

I am using postman so am able to construct the call exactly how it should be.  There is no discernible difference between the two that work and don't work.

Comment: Because of the problem with complex types I think it's a got habit to just specifiy 'contentType: 'application/json;' and json stringify the js object and then there's no need to use the [FromBody] attribute.

Comment: In my case some of the model parameters are omitted by parser for no reason! Model fields of type `DateTime?` aren't parsed from strings 'yyyy-MM-dd' in POST but parsed in GET with `[FromUri]` set for model.

Comment: If anyone is having same problems with parsing some of the model parameters: attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof (YourCustomConverter))]` is the solution for such fields.

Comment: How do you pass some simple types *and* a complex type?

Comment: @Shavais,  AFAIK, it is not possible (by default). Just club all the data in a single DTO.

Comment: @Shavais Can you please check my question? I can't solve it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545603/mvc-rest-api-unable-to-get-collection-in-json-parameter/40545923#40545923

Comment: I am getting this error: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: i owe u a party dude

Comment: And every other year we'll have to work out how to do it all over again.

Answer (score 71):

Working with POST in webapi can be tricky!
Would like to add to the already correct answer..

Will focus specifically on POST as dealing with GET is trivial. I don't think many would be searching around for resolving an issue with GET with webapis. Anyways..

If your question is - In MVC Web Api, how to- - Use custom action method names other than the generic HTTP verbs? - Perform multiple posts? - Post multiple simple types? - Post complex types via jQuery?

Then the following solutions may help:

First, to use **Custom** Action Methods in Web API, add a web api route as:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}");
}
```

And then you may create action methods like:

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestMethod([FromBody]string value)
{
    return "Hello from http post web api controller: " + value;
}
```

Now, fire the following jQuery from your browser console

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:33649/api/TestApi/TestMethod',
    data: {'':'hello'},
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ console.log(data) }
});
```

Second, to **perform multiple posts**, It is simple, create multiple action methods and decorate with the [HttpPost] attrib. Use the [ActionName("MyAction")] to assign custom names, etc. Will come to jQuery in the fourth point below

Third, First of all, posting multiple **SIMPLE** types in a single action is not possible.
Moreover, there is a **special format** to post even a **single simple type** (apart from passing the parameter in the query string or REST style). 
This was the point that had me banging my head with Rest Clients (like Fiddler and Chrome's Advanced REST client extension) and hunting around the web for almost 5 hours when eventually, the following URL proved to be of help. Will quote the relevant content for the link might turn dead!

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
in the request header and add a = before the JSON statement:
={"Name":"Turbo Tina","Email":"na@Turbo.Tina"}
```

PS: Noticed the *peculiar syntax*?

http://forums.asp.net/t/1883467.aspx?The+received+value+is+null+when+I+try+to+Post+to+my+Web+Api

Anyways, let us get over that story. Moving on:

Fourth, **posting complex types** via jQuery, ofcourse, $.ajax() is going to promptly come in the role:

Let us say the action method accepts a Person object which has an id and a name. So, from javascript:

```
var person = { PersonId:1, Name:"James" }
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://mydomain/api/TestApi/TestMethod',
    data: JSON.stringify(person),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){ console.log(data) }
});
```

And the action will look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestMethod(Person person)
{
    return "Hello from http post web api controller: " + person.Name;
}
```

All of the above, worked for me!! Cheers!

Comment: I seem to hit this problem every few months, most of the time I eventually solve it, but this time I have given up. None of the tips above solve it for me, so I decided to bin this as an approach. If it's SO hard to get right, why bother? It's only a convenience anyway - just take the content in as a string and use newtonsoft to transform it. Done. Took probably 30 seconds to solve it the "hard" way after trying for about an hour to solve it the "easy" way. I'm not wild about the approach, but is there a fundamental problem with it?

Comment: PS: In WebApi2, we can now use Route Decorators. So this issue is primarily, addressed. 
 http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Would like to add an observation. Sometimes, the reason for the model-binding to fail (null) on the WebAPI side, when passing a complex type (ex: DTO), is that one or more properties in the model will be incompatible (or fail to parse). Eg. A Guid property being assigned an invalid GUID.
In this case, try using the default/empty values for all the object properties and try again.

Answer (score 12):

I've just been playing with this and discovered a rather odd result. Say you have public properties on your class in C# like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string contact_name;
    public string company_name;
}
```

then you must do the JSON.stringify trick as suggested by Shyju and call it like this:

```
var customer = {contact_name :"Scott",company_name:"HP"};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data :JSON.stringify(customer),
    url: "api/Customer",
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

However, if you define getters and setters on your class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string contact_name { get; set; }
    public string company_name { get; set; }
}
```

then you can call it much more simply:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data :customer,
    url: "api/Customer"
});
```

This uses the HTTP header:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I'm not quite sure what's happening here but it looks like a bug (feature?) in the framework. Presumably the different binding methods are calling different "adapters", and while the adapter for application/json one works with public properties, the one for form encoded data doesn't.

I have no idea which would be considered best practice though.

Comment: Properties vs fields is why its different.  Properties are the best practice.  What you call properties in that first example are in fact, fields.  When you put a get/set on them, they then have an auto created backing field which makes them properties.

Comment: This is so true, and odd. Normal classes with only fields won't bind to form posts, but properties will. BTW: Still doesn't explain why this is the case...? I can only guess the internal logic will only bind JSON data to fields, and form post data to properties, and that's simply it...?

Comment: It's the case because the code only looks for properties.  Since using public fields is *not* best practice, the MS team decided not to allow *not* best practice scenarios, pretty good reason IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **JSON.stringify()** to get the string in JSON format, ensure that while making the AJAX call you pass below mentioned attributes:

- contentType: 'application/json'

Below is the give jquery code to make ajax post call to asp.net web api:

```js
var product =
    JSON.stringify({
        productGroup: "Fablet",
        productId: 1,
        productName: "Lumia 1525 64 GB",
        sellingPrice: 700
    });

$.ajax({
    URL: 'http://localhost/api/Products',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: product,
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Update Error occurred - ' + error);
    }
});
```

Comment: dataType is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your WebAPI service is expecting a strongly typed object with a structure that matches the JSON that you are passing.  And make sure that you stringify the JSON that you are POSTing.

Here is my JavaScript (using AngluarJS):

```
$scope.updateUserActivity = function (_objuserActivity) {
        $http
        ({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'your url here',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            data: JSON.stringify(_objuserActivity)
        })
        .then(function (response)
        {
            alert("success");
        })
        .catch(function (response)
        {
            alert("failure");
        })
        .finally(function ()
        {
        });
```

And here is my WebAPI Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public string POSTMe([FromBody]Models.UserActivity _activity)
{
    return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following code to return data in the json format ,instead of the xml -Web API 2 :-**

*Put following line in the Global.asax file*

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@model MVCClient.Models.ProductDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductDetails";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Save").click(function () {
            var ProductDetails = new Object();
            ProductDetails.ProductName =  $("#txt_productName").val();
            ProductDetails.ProductDetail = $("#txt_desc").val();
            ProductDetails.Price= $("#txt_price").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:24481/api/Product/addProduct",
                type: "Post",
                dataType:'JSON',
                data:ProductDetails, 

                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Updated Successfully');
                    //window.location.href = "../Index";
                },
                error: function (msg) { alert(msg); }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
<h2>ProductDetails</h2>

<form id="form1" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProductDetails</legend>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <input id="txt_productName" type="text" name="fname">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDetail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <input id="txt_desc" type="text" name="fname">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDetail)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            <input id="txt_price" type="text" name="fname">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
        </div>



        <p>
            <input id="Save" type="button" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>

</form>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft gave a good example of doing this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

First validate the request

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

and than use the serialized data.

```
Content = new StringContent(update.Status)
```

Here 'Status' is a field in the complex type. Serializing is done by .NET, no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

1)In your client side you can send you http.post request in string like below

```
var IndexInfo = JSON.stringify(this.scope.IndexTree);
this.$http.post('../../../api/EvaluationProcess/InsertEvaluationProcessInputType', "'" + IndexInfo + "'" ).then((response: any) => {}
```

2)Then in your web api controller you can deserialize it

```
public ApiResponce InsertEvaluationProcessInputType([FromBody]string IndexInfo)
    {
var des = (ApiReceivedListOfObjects<TempDistributedIndex>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(DecryptedProcessInfo, typeof(ApiReceivedListOfObjects<TempDistributedIndex>));}
```

3)Your ApiReceivedListOfObjects class should be like below

```
public class ApiReceivedListOfObjects<T>
    {
        public List<T> element { get; set; }

    }
```

4)make sure that your serialized string (IndexInfo here) becomes like below structure before JsonConvert.DeserializeObject command in step 2

```
var resp = @"
    {
        ""element"": [
        {
            ""A"": ""A Jones"",
            ""B"": ""500015763""
        },
        {
            ""A"": ""B Smith"",
            ""B"": ""504986213""
        },
        {
            ""A"": ""C Brown"",
            ""B"": ""509034361""
        }
        ]
    }";
```