# Is forcing POST data to begin with = a good idea?

Tags: http, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an api using .NET Mvc Web Api. It will accept POST requests with JSON as the payload. If I want to use the `FromBody` method to retrieve the POST data, the payload has to begin with an equals sign (=). (That makes it a key-value-pair with a nameless key.)

Too me this seems a bit strange, and I'm wondering if this syntax is somewhat accepted, or simply a Web Api quirk that I should avoid exposing to my consumers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to post JSON to a web API action without beginning it with "=". It is difficult to know what is going on without seeing some code. The first thing that I can think of that might be wrong is that the Content-type header is not being set correctly. It should be

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I'm guessing the content-type is being set to

```
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

or

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data
```

Comment: As I understand it this is by design. Look here for example:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types
My question is really if it's acceptable to expose this to consumers. OTOH, if you're saying it's not even an issue in Web Api, then my question is irrelevant.

Comment: What's posting to the method? Is it a web form in an HTML page, an AJAX request, other systems?

Comment: The example you linked to shows how to submit a form as application/x-www-form-urlencoded. You can pass a JSON string as a form key / value pair (which is why you need the "="), but the preferred way to do it would be to create a JSON object and post it as application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The accepted answer here might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object

Comment: Thanks, your answers combined made me understand!