# Angular $http.post: cannot send objects with data to server. Data as a string works, as an object - not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send data to server using this function:

```
var _register = function (email, password, passconfirmation) {
    var data = {
        "Email": email,
        "Password": password,
        "ConfirmPassword": passconfirmation
    };

    return $http.post('/api/Account/Register', data, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
}
```

It doesn't work. My ASP.net web api doesn't receive any data. Every variable on server-side is "null". But when I do this this way:

```
var _register = function (email, password, passconfirmation) {
    var data = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password + "&ConfirmPassword=" + passconfirmation;

    return $http.post('/api/Account/Register', data, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });
}
```

Everything works great. The problem is: the first way is much clearer than the second one, so I want to use the first one. But I have no idea what's wrong :/

Comment: See this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the headers in post or change the headers like the following

```
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

your code should be

```
var _register = function (email, password, passconfirmation) {
    var data = {
        "Email": email,
        "Password": password,
        "ConfirmPassword": passconfirmation
    };

    return $http.post('/api/Account/Register', data, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue in the past. Try

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

Before passing it to the post. The object binder on the other side should be able to accept it then.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do like this ..

> since AngularJS, transmits data using

**`Content-Type: application/json`**

```
 return $http.post('/api/Account/Register', {'dataObj' : data  }, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    });
```

***Your data should be a key/val pair, try:***
data variable will get to the server under the parameter `dataObj`