# Posting to ASP.NET WebApi server from AngularJS client

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post strings from an AngularJS application (using `$http`) to a server built on ASP.NET WebApi, but I get 404 as soon as I add a parameter.

The client code is this

```
$scope.add = function () {
    // ...cut...
    $http({ method: "POST", url: url, data: { fileString: "test string" }}).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            $log.info(response.data);
        }
    );
}
```

The server code is

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadExcel(string fileString) {
    // cut
}
```

I get a 404, but if I remove the parameter on server side it works, so i can use a server side code like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadExcel() {
    // cut
}
```

What is wrong? Should I pass the data in a different way? I tried different combination but I can't get it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is send a string, not a JSON object as you are doing right now with `{ fileString: "test string" }`. When I want to send a string, what I normally do is that I send data from Angular like this:

```
$http.post("/Search/QuickSearch?searchQuery="+ searchString);
```

And my controller I make ready to receive a string like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult QuickSearch(string searchQuery)
{
    // cut
}
```

If I want to send a JSON object, I tell my controller what it should expect, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveActivity(ActivityEditForm form);
{
    // cut
}

public class ActivityEditForm
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And then send my JSON from Angular like this:

```
$http.post("/Activity/SaveActivity", { form: activity });
```

Comment: this workaround can't work because my parameter string is too big

Comment: Try sending it as a JSON object and then preparing your controller for the data. Have updated my answer with how I handle that approach.

Comment: Due to some configuration dependent glitches I suggest to always use your   "JSON object" solution. Even if it's a single string I decided to create a C# object.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you had some problems with your solution, but I'm glad that I could be of any help. I myself is rather satisfied with my solution myself, if has served me well for the last two years :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you should capture the request send by Angular. By default, Angular send parameters in a json string in request body.

I'm not sure wether Asp.net can parse them from json string in body.

So, you can try to add the below codes (also need jQuery)

```
angular.module('yourApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return $.param(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I think changing the C# WebApi backend is much more clear, but this should be a viable solution if someone doesn't have control on the backend

Answer (score 2):

The first error is in the controller, `[FromBody]` should be used with the input parameter.

```
public IHttpActionResult UploadExcel([FromBody]string fileString)
```

Then the `data` variable on the client should be a single string, so

```
$http({ method: "POST", url: url, data: "test string" }).then(
```

Anyway I found some issue with this solution later, it seems the simplest but I suggest to avoid it.

---

**Best solution**

Thank to @Squazz answer and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object) I strongly suggest a change in the webapi controller, client was correct. Just introduce a class to handle a single string and adapt the input parameter

```
// new class with a single string
public class InputData {
    public string fileString { get; set; }
}

// new controller 
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadExcel([FromBody] InputData myInput) {
    string fileString = myInput.fileString;
    // cut
}
```

This way JSON code from the client is automatically parsed and it's easy to change the data input.

**Extra tip**

`$scope.add` angular function was correct as in the question, but here is a more complete example

```
$scope.testDelete = function () {
    var url = "http://localhost/yourAppLink/yourControllerName/UploadExcel";
    var data = ({ fileString: "yourStringHere" });
    $http({ method: "POST", url: url, data: data }).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            console.log("done, here is the answer: ", response.data);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("an error occurred");
        }
    );
}
```