# Unable to send multiple records to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am sending records from WEBApi to the controller. However, I am unable to more than one record to the controller. The parameter "PDFData" shows two records when I hover over it. But when I hover over ticketData parameter, I see only one record.

How do I send more than one records?

WebAPI:

```
export function buildTicketPDF(PDFData): JQueryXHR {
    return $.ajax({
        url: myApp.utils.getAppUrl() + "/api/BuildTicketPDF",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ PDFData: PDFData }),
        contentType: "application/json",
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<PoDataTable> BuildTicketPDF(JObject ticketData)
{
    return boASNTool.BuildTicketPDF(ticketData);
}
```

Comment: Replace `type:"POST"` by `method:"POST"`. But I don't think that `JObject` can be dynamically created from request.

Comment: Did you try: `contentType:"application/json"` with JSON request. Have a look [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Comment: @rajeshmag I already have  'contentType:"application/json"'  in my code

Comment: Can you add an example in JSON of `PDFData` containing multiple records?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ ticketData: PDFData }),
```

Comment: still sends one record

Comment: You should expand on your code and explain why it answers the question.