# WebApi request parameters are null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

**Here are my models**

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is my WebApi method**

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetStudentInfo(Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

**Here is my call from JS (This one works)**

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:50067/api/Students/SetStudentInfo",
  data: {
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Smith"
  },
  success: function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

**Here is my call from JS (This one DOES NOT work)**

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:50067/api/Students/SetStudentInfo",
  data: {
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Smith",
    Courses: null
  },
  success: function (xhr) {
    console.log(xhr);
  },
  error: function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

When I send up the second request, the entire student on the WebApi method is null; it's something to do with adding in nested objects but I'm not sure why, or how to fix this.

I've tried stringifying the data, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: did you try  Courses: [ ]?

Comment: @tmg yep same problem

Comment: try `data: {   "FirstName": "John",    "LastName": "Smith"  },`

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20226220/2931427

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with specifying content type for request data as `application/json` and also you need to serialize your data using `JSON.stringify()` function.

You can copy the code below:

```
var requestData = {
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Smith",
        Courses: null
    };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:50067/api/Students/SetStudentInfo",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

Also one tip. Your web api controller should not be `void`. Api controller should always return something, for example `IHttpActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SetStudentInfo(Student student)
{
    //process your data
    return Ok();// or BadRequest()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `content-type` like

```
contentType:"application/json"
```

Also you need to use `JSON.stringify()` method to convert your data to JSON format when you send it, You can read more details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226220/2931427

#### OLD Answer

In your action try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetStudentInfo([FromBody] Student student)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: complex types are read from the request body by default. This will not cause any error but will do nothing.