# how to post and accept long text to ASP.net web api?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to figure out the parameters and class fields to post and accept "build notes"(example text below) info,I am trying to design my controller as follows?would the following work for accepting a long text?

Controller:

```
public IEnumerable<class name> GetBuildNotes([FromBody] Buildnotes buildNotes>)
{
...........
........
}
```

Buildnotes class:

```
public class buildnotes
{
public string build_notes. --> this goes to a database column build_notes of type longtext
.....
```

}

Long text:

```
    CHECKOUT POINT
    cld3 - 1855314
    cmn - 1855287

    Known issue
    [testsuite: STA_5G_VHT]: COMDEBUG-276224: consistent crash : APPS Crash - Kernel BUG at ffffff82dc55994c [PC at reg_todo+0x1dc/0x260] [LR at reg_todo]
    if you observe build loading issue.please use fastboot.exe path : \\\8998_adb_drivers
    Latest META only supported on BIN1 MTP. With BINA sometimes its works. but observed random boot-up crash
    BIN B MTP doesn't boot up with latest target meta
    Expected behavior :Bootloader UI updated with Boot verify feature in UEFI where the signing of the images is verified.
    You can use below script to determine the Bin / Sub BIN type and IDDq leakage values thru adb.
    Bring up device in adb mode
    Source : \\location\team\LA\8998_hw_type\FinalScript
    Usage : python bining.py
    Please run "adb disable-verity" to avoid "adb remount/push" related issue
    Sl4a/ PMC/ Acts/ Comms:Google_testing
    $[apps_crm]\source\google_testing
    WAPI build
    CCX build location
    e
    HOT FIX
    HW used for BIT sanity
    Recommendation to use MPT with chipname 2.0 card. please replace chipname card on MTP having MCN ends with 001/003/005 

    CDT programming forV2 HW
    http://qwiki.company.com/qct-drvsw/8998

Pre-built wiki
http://qwiki.company.com/com_wCOM/com-CBI/Build_With_External_AU#BUILDING_DRIVER_POINTING_TO_APPS_CRM
http://qwiki.company.com/com_wCOM/com-CBI/Build_With_External_AU#Build_ROME_and_chip_for_SP_:_com1234.LA.0.1

    Build loading procedure
    Load BIT (CI) Meta

    ENGG WLAN FW load on top of BIT META
    adb root
    adb remount
    adb shell mount -o rw,remount /firmware
    adb push wlanmdsp.mbn /firmware/image
    adb reboot

    ENGG BT FW load on top of BIT META
    adb root
    adb remount
    adb shell mount -o rw,remount /bt_firmware
    adb push * /bt_firmware/image
    adb reboot
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen has a point, and I don't see where he's being rude. What's the harm in your telling us what happens when you try this out? And I disagree with your assessment of SO's "bad rep". Among professional coders looking for a high quality question and answer repository, this site has one of the highest reputations of all. The problems come when new programmers get disappointed because they ask questions assuming that this is a traditional help site when in fact it is not, nor was it ever built to be.

Comment: @user2125837 I try my best not to be rude, ever. In this case it is just very time wasting for the asker and others to send an incomplete piece of code and ask if that's the way things would work. We have no information about the actual environment or application. Sending "long text" can be done in a million ways and that text isn't really even long. So there is nothing to answer here even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, I'm guessing you just need to ensure that the object you're passing from your client application matches your *Buildnotes* class structure.

Try this:
[How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)