# get all values from list of array to catch JSON.stringify data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, stringify

this my code to push all item in gridview to array

```
   var arrInputSparepart = [];
   $("#Gridview1").find(".InputSparepart").each(function () {
      arrInputSparepart.push($(this).text());
   });
   var explodedInputSparepart = $.map(arrInputSparepart, function (InputSparepartName, InputSparepartIndex) {
      return ([InputSparepartName]);
   });
   alert(explodedInputSparepart); //this is return list = **string1,string2** etc in display alert
```

how i can get that array to put it that to json??

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://mydomain/api/TestApi/TestMethod',
**data: JSON.stringify(????????), //what else here??**
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){ console.log(data) }});
```

Comment: Maybe some information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object

Comment: i am using asp.net not mvc, but thanks for replying

Comment: Similar asp ones when searching for title

Comment: pls help. i've been edited my question