# asp.net ajax not sending data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My AJAX is not sending data to my http post controller.

My controller:

```
[Route("api/sendingData")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody] int propertyID)
    {
        return string.Format("Test");
    }
}
```

My AJAX:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "api/sendingData",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'propertyID': '1'
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.debug(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
            console.debug(xhr);
            var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
            if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
            alert(err);
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to send the `propertyID=1`. However, when I debug my controller, it shows `propertyID=0`.

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Please test this: `data: { propertyID: JSON.stringify('1')}`

Comment: Thanks. But still the same problem

Comment: Try it by removing the single quotes :     data: {propertyID: 1 },

Comment: Solution: data : { "" : 1 }. I don't know why

Comment: Also, the [FromBody] could be the problem. What happens if you remove it or use [FromUri] instead?

Comment: Take a look at [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might look weird but you're only sending one value, not a model, so the stringify is JSON.stringify(value)

```
var propertyID = 1;
$.ajax({
    url: "api/sendingData",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(propertyID),
    success: function (result) {
        console.debug(result);
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
        console.debug(xhr);
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Also I have removed dataType json because your action method is not returning json but a string. Now I'm getting success.