# Convert request from GET to POST in ASP.NET CORE APPLICATION

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, get

I need to convert the request from get to post in two contexts:
- in the case of the standard controller
- in the case of web api
in an asp.net core c # project.

Here are the method declarations.
Standard controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(string id)
```

Web Api Controller:

```
[HttpGet("{deviceIdorId}/{action2}")] 
public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBTelemetry>> GetAsync(string deviceIdorId,string action2)
```

What should I do?

Thanks,

Simone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for convert HttpGet method to post you can create a view model to pass data. for example:

Web Api

```cs
public class ApiDto
{
      public string deviceIdorId { get; set;}
      public string action2{ get; set;}
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost("ActionName")] 
public async Task<IEnumerable<CosmosDBTelemetry>> ActionName(ApiDto dto)
```

Controller:

```cs
public class IdDto
{
      public string Id{ get; set;}
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(IdDto id)
```

Comment: Could you please tell me also what I have to do to call the method ? I mark your post as the answer. Could you vote my question, please? Thanks a lot Simone

Comment: Good luck ;). you must pass the parameters from the body to method. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20226220/7086678) to send data to post actions in api