# asp.net mvc, jQuery/JavaScript - passing a variable (an object) to an action method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I execute a jQuery $.ajax function in a asp.net partial view to call a controller action method to set a session variable.

I stringify the var object I create.

If I use:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

it does NOT go into the controller action method, but the

```
 success: function
```

returns an alert.

[image]

My console log shows the objects properties have values.

[image]

**Why does it not go into the controller action method?**

---

In this scenario, if I use:

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```

it does go into the controller action method, but the argument it receives is NULL

[image]

yet my console log shows the objects properties have values. And the

```
 success: function
```

returns an alert.

**Why is the input parameter a null?**

---

The partial view:

```
@model GbngWebClient.Models.LikeOrDislikeVM

<style>
.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
}

    .fa:hover {
        color: blue;
    }

/* I added. */
.my-size {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.my-button {
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
     /* To make the buttons stay on the same line. */
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
<div>
    <button class="blogLike my-button fa fa-thumbs-up"><span class="my-size, likeCount"> : @Model.LikeCount </span></button>
    <button class="blogDisLike my-button fa fa-thumbs-down"><span class="my-size, dislikeCount"> : @Model.DisLikeCount</span></button>
</div>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // For testing:
    console.log('Here at ready. ');

    // JavaScript needs it as 'false'. So using these 'const' to convert them.
    const False = false, True = true;

    // Set the disabled attributes and color.
    SetLike(@Model.LikeDisabled);
    SetDisLike(@Model.DisLikeDisabled);

    // Create the variable in the image of the LikeOrDislikeVM view model.
    var holdLikeOrDislikeVM = {
        BlogId : @Model.BlogId,
        UserId: @Model.UserId,
        LikeCount: @Model.LikeCount,
        DisLikeCount: @Model.DisLikeCount,
        LikeDisabled: @Model.LikeDisabled,
        DisLikeDisabled: @Model.DisLikeDisabled,
    };

    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.BlogId);
    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.UserId);
    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.LikeCount);
    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.DisLikeCount);
    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.LikeDisabled);
    console.log("hold: " + holdLikeOrDislikeVM.DisLikeDisabled);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
        data: { likeOrDislikeVM: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM) },
        //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success. Response: " + response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to SetModelSessionVar! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    })
                  

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Set the disabled attribute to true or false.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function SetLike(disabledSwitch) {
        // For testing:
        console.log('Here at Setlike. ' + disabledSwitch);

        $(".blogLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == true )
        {
            // Show by color that it was previously liked.
            $(".blogLike").css('color', 'green');
        }

        if (disabledSwitch == false)
        {
            // Show by color that it can be clicked.
            $(".blogLike").css('color', 'black');
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     // Set the disabled attribute to true or false.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function SetDisLike(disabledSwitch) {
        // For testing:
        console.log('Here at SetDisLike. ' + disabledSwitch);

        $(".blogDisLike").attr('disabled', disabledSwitch);

        if (disabledSwitch == true)
        {
            // Show by color that it was previously disliked.
            $(".blogDisLike").css('color', 'green');
        }

        if (disabledSwitch == false)
        {
          // Show by color that it can be clicked.
            $(".blogDisLike").css('color', 'black');
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

---

The view model:

```
namespace GbngWebClient.Models
{
    public class LikeOrDislikeVM
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int LikeCount { get; set; }
        public int DisLikeCount { get; set; }
        public bool LikeDisabled { get; set; }
        public bool DisLikeDisabled { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

The controller actions method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetModelSessionVar(LikeOrDislikeVM likeOrDislikeVM)
{
   // Sets a model session variable according to the argument passed in.
   Session["likeOrDislikeVM"] = likeOrDislikeVM;
}
```

---

Per discussions with freedomn-m, I discovered:

For a controller action method of:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetModelSessionVar(string likeOrDislikeVM)
{
   Session["likeOrDislikeVM"] = likeOrDislikeVM;
}
```

This is the only 1 that works (comes into the controller method as: {"BlogId":40,"UserId":3,"LikeCount":0,"DisLikeCount":1,"LikeDisabled":false,"DisLikeDisabled":true}):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: { likeOrDislikeVM: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM) },
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

Does not work (comes into the controller method as: null):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM),
     contentType: "application/json",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

Does not work (comes into the controller method as: null):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM),
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

Does not work (does not come into the controller method and nothing in console shown):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: { likeOrDislikeVM: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM)},
     contentType: "application/json",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

---

Now for a controller action method of:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetModelSessionVar(LikeOrDislikeVM likeOrDislikeVM)
{
   Session["likeOrDislikeVM"] = likeOrDislikeVM;
}
```

This is the only 1 that works (comes into the controller method as: {an image of the model - which is what I want, not a string as above):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: { likeOrDislikeVM: holdLikeOrDislikeVM },
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

[image]

Note: I had to create a JavaScript object from the view model defined in this partial view as it seems I could not pass that view model to the controller method. Not sure why. I don' get why I can't use the view model.

Using the view model defined in this partial view to pass to the controller method:
Does not work (comes into the controller method as: null):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: { likeOrDislikeVM: '@Model' },
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

Using the view model defined in this partial view to pass to the controller method:
Does not work (does not come into the controller, console shows: GbngWebClient is not defined ReferenceError: GbngWebClient is not defined):

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '@Url.Action("SetModelSessionVar", "BlogPublished")',
     data: { likeOrDislikeVM: @Model},
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert("Critical Error: something");
     }
 })
```

Comment: If you `JSON.stringify` then your action parameter will need to be `public void SetModelSessionVar(string likeOrDislikeVM)` - which it's not, so it doesn't match the parameter, so you get `null`

Comment: OK. I changed the action method signature. It now works if I change to: contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", Comes in as: {"BlogId":40,"UserId":3,"LikeCount":0,"DisLikeCount":1,"LikeDisabled":false,"DisLikeDisabled":true}. But with contentType: "application/json", it does not get to the controller. Per this post, the parameter can be defined as the class model and the contentType can be:  "application/json". See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-an-object

Comment: The difference between that answer and yours is that they are passing each parameter at the "root" while you have an extra parameter name: `data: { likeOrDislikeVM: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM) },` should be `data: JSON.stringify(holdLikeOrDislikeVM),` then the model binder will match the js names to your model names.  That post is also confusing because it says you "need to use json.stringify" - you don't, but if you don't then don't use `application/json` - the two go together.  it's also an answer for web-api, not mvc which works(worked) slightly differently.

Comment: freedomn-m, I tried your suggestion and added my findings above. See: Per discussions with freedomn-m, I discovered: