# C# MVC pass parameters from View to Controller using dotnetfiddle

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am learning C# MVC using dotnetfiddle web to write code.
I have created a new project with the default code of dotnetfiddle for MVC type, but I want to display the **question** in the alert instead of the **answer**.

I want to know how to pass parameters to the controller from the view.

This is the ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
    data: JSON.stringify({Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()}),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(resp) {
        openAlert(resp.result);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            openAlert("ERROR: " + errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

And this is the controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAnswer(string question)
{               
    int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
    var answer = _db[index];
    return Json(new { result = question});
}
```

You can check and test the code here: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UpivQ5) (Edit: it will be a good answer if it works here)

Comment: In order to send JSON you need `data: JSON.stringify({Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()}),` or jQuery will send `Answer=&Question=xyz` instead

Comment: I have already changed ```data: {Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()},``` to ```data: JSON.stringify({Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()}),``` but I get a null var in the controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to pass json POST data to Web API method as an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226169/how-to-pass-json-post-data-to-web-api-method-as-an-object)

Comment: Did not work for me. Maybe the error comes for another reason but I doubt it because is the example code autogenerated by dotnetfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These code changes will work for you. If you wanna verify check the fiddle. [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/19PdG6)

> **Client side Changes**

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetAnswer", controller="Home"})',
                    data: {"Answer": '', "Question": $('#Question').val()},
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(resp) {
                            openAlert(resp.Question);
                        },
                        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                            openAlert("ERROR: " + errorThrown); 
                        }
                    });
```

> **Server Side Changes**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetAnswer(SampleViewModel model)
        {               
            int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
            var answer = _db[index];
            return Json(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I used to pass parameters to controller

First, assign the parameter you want to pass to a variable with the value from the
input id as stated in your dotnetfiddle

```js
var questionParam = $("#Question").val();
```

Then for passing it to AJAX, I think your method is already correct, this is how I do it

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/GetAnswer?question=' + questionParam ,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(resp) {
        openAlert(resp.result);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            openAlert("ERROR: " + errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

This method works for me in my project, if the value is a string I think you don't need to stringify the value.

I'm still a beginner as well so maybe my method is wrong or not the best way to do it, I hope it helps you.

Comment: You're inserting the question (unescaped btw) as GET param, not as POST param.

Comment: If I do that I get a sintex error. I provide a source code to test it without installing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value of the question in the action because your action has got a single parameter `string question` in there.

What you need to do is:

1. Send a json object from the view
2. In the action user a model with two properties (Answer and Question) to get the value sent by the view
3. Then in the action you decide what data you need to send to view

**View:**
Send JSON object to action:

```
JSON.stringify({Answer: '', Question: $('#Question').val()})
```

When you get the data returned from controller:

```
openAlert(resp.Answer);
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetAnswer(MyQA model)
{
    // model.Answer
    // model.Question
    // Your business logic goes here

    return Json(new { result = model});
}
```

Here is the MyQA class:

```
public class MyQA
{
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Question{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already did the changes you propose but the alert still  not working. Can you check it in your browser please: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UpivQ5)

Comment: @Kaido can you point out where you are facing the problem? And what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

dotnetfiddle had a problem with this line: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

change script to :

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
  if ($('form').valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("GetAnswer", "Home")',
      data: {
        Answer: '',
        Question: $('#Question').val()
      },
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(resp) {
        openAlert('Answer :' + resp.Answer + ' -----Question : ' + resp.Question);
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        openAlert("ERROR: " + textStatus);
      }
    });
  } else {
    closeAlert();
  }
});
```

change action `GetAnswer` to :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAnswer(string Answer,string Question)
{               
   int index = _rnd.Next(_db.Count);
     var answer = _db[index];
     return Json(new {Answer = answer,Question = Question});
}
```